# How can I make camera movements more natural?

Tags: python, math, 3d, camera, trigonometry

I'm struggling to make the camera movements feel more natural. Currently, the camera movements are rigid and don't smoothly follow user input or animations.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
running = True
mouse_down = False
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get((QUIT,MOUSEBUTTONUP,MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)):
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mouse_down = False
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_down = True
            xcoor = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if mouse_down and (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - xcoor[0] != 0 or pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] - xcoor[1]):
        condition = True
        camera[1].z += (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - xcoor[0]) * 0.1
        camera[1].y -= (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] - xcoor[1]) * 0.1
        xcoor = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    else:
        condition = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        camera[0].x -= 0.1
        condition = True
    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
        camera[0].x += 0.1
        condition = True
    if keys[K_UP]:
        camera[0].z -= 0.1
        condition = True
    if keys[K_DOWN]:
        camera[0].z += 0.1
        condition = True
    if keys[K_w]:
        camera[0].y += 0.1
        condition = True
    if keys[K_s]:
        camera[0].y -= 0.1
        condition = True
```

I initialize the camera position and orientation using a set of vectors and angles. However, when I try to move or rotate the camera, the movements are abrupt and not smooth at all.

What techniques or approaches can I use to improve the fluidity and naturalness of camera movements in my Pygame raytracer? Are there specific algorithms or libraries that would help with this?

Answer (score 0):

While It wasn't generally a pygame code (It's generally mathematical)

```
    if mouse_down and (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - xcoor[0] != 0 or pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] - xcoor[1]):
        condition = True
        x -= (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - xcoor[0]) * 3
        y -= (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] - xcoor[1]) * 3
        xcoor = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        camera[1].x = camera[0].x + sin(radians(x)) * cos(radians(y))
        camera[1].y = camera[0].y + sin(radians(y))
        camera[1].z = camera[0].z + cos(radians(x)) * cos(radians(y))
```